# A question on eigenvalue of parametric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, oc.optimization-and-control

1. Is there a way to efficiently check if all matrices in the following set are [Hurwitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_matrix#Hurwitz_stable_matrices) stable (eigenvalues strictly in the left-hand plane)?$$\left\{ A \in \Bbb R^{n \times n} : \ell_{i,j}\leq A_{i,j} \leq u_{i,j} \right\}$$ I could work with eigenvalues on the imaginary axis, too. I am looking for a result similar to that of [Kharitonov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kharitonov%27s_theorem)'s.
2. Given affine function $A : \Bbb R^m \to \Bbb R^{n \times n}$, where $m < n$, is there a similar result for checking the stability of the following set? $$\left\{ A(u_1, u_2, \dots, u_m): 0 \leq u_1, u_2,\dots, u_m \leq 1 \right\}$$

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but there is a notion of sign-stable patterns. These are matrices whose entries belong to $\{-,0,+\}$, such that every compatible realisation is a stable matrix. See exercise #29 on my webpage http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/serre/DPF/exobis.pdf .

Comment: @DenisSerre Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo (i) preferably, strictly in LHP (if a condition exists for closed LHP, can work with that too), (ii) A is real, (iii) size of A can be arbitrary (and, m<n in the second case).

Comment: Good pointers to start with are "verified computation" and "interval arithmetic", since what you have is essentially an interval matrix.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, a sufficient condition would be the existence of a symmetric positive function such that

$$A^TP+PA\prec0$$

for all $A\in\left\{ A \in \Bbb R^{n \times n} : A_{i,j}\in\{\ell_{i,j},u_{i,j}\}\right\}$. This follows from a simple application of Lyapunov theorem. The issue is that it has an exponential complexity in the dimension of the system. In fact, there are $2^{n^2}$ inequalities to verify.

If the matrices satisfy a particular structure, this can be simplified. For instance, if $A$ is Metzler, then a necessary and sufficient condition is that the upper-bound $A$ with $A_{ij}=u_{ij}$ is Hurwitz stable.

The same applies for the second question.

Comment: Why is it enough to check the $2^{n^2}$ vertices? This does not seem obvious to me.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni This is a consequence of the convexity of set of all possible matrices $A$.